# Как узнать тип переменной в PyCharm Python

Tags: python, pycharm

В `python` узнать тип переменной `a` можно, вписав команду `print(type(a))`. Можно ли в `PyCharm` узнать тип переменной, наведя на неё мышкой или другим быстрым способом, не набирая строки кода для каждой переменной?

Comment: Можно использовать дебаггер в PyCharm и его панель с переменными (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/part-1-debugging-python-code.html#watching)

Answer (score 3):

Ставишь каретку на переменную -> <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> (View -> Type Info). Если не сможет вывести тип будет `Any`.

[image: type hint popup in PyCharm]

Comment: А не, действительно не так работает, как если просто мышкой навести.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать типизацию и модуль `typing` для более сложных типов.

Как пример имеем функцию с описанными типами переменных (их описывать можно не только в функции). PyCharm будет понимать, какая переменная кем является, и предлагать методы для этого типа. Спомощью модуля `typing` можно описать какие ожидаются элементы внутри iterable объектов, Union типы (когда несколько типов может быть) и тд.

Понимает что переменная строка и предлагает методы для строки.
[image: Понимает что переменная строка и предлагает методы для строки.]

Понимает что переменная dict и показывает методы для него
[image: Понимает что перменная dict и показывает методы для него]

Понимает что ключ переменно - tuple и показывает методы для него.
[image: Понимает что ключ переменно - tuple и показывает методы для него.]
и тд

Так же если ввести в функцию недопустимые типы, PyCharm подскажет Вам.
[image]

С собственной структурой, аналогично знает что это за переменная и предлагает её атрибуты.
[image]